# Search in array with %LIKE% like as SQL

Tags: javascript, arrays

Because SQLite is very slow, I select all of my needed records and store in an array.

Now in my application I have a search section which user can search part of string on this array.

my array structure is :

```
[
   {
   name : 'Black',
   family : 'Dragon',
   email : 'black.dragon@blahblahblah.com'
   }
]
```

I have 3 input fields in my page which users can enter some characters and I should search in this array and return the index of matched values.

for example if my user enter `bla` or `lack` or `@blahblah`, my program should return the index of this value.

Is it possible? How should I work ?

Comment: You would have to iterate over each object and then use regular expression (regex) for each field to get the matching values OR If you do not want to reinvent the wheel, you could use [taffydb](http://www.taffydb.com/), which provides database like features in JavaScript.

Comment: SQLite is actually generally very fast for most queries, provided you've set up your indices correctly. (Insertion is another matter.) In any case, if you want to avoid scanning every single record (which should actually be fast enough depending on the number of records), you're going to need some sort of [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing#Index_data_structures). I suggest using a suffix trie if you really need the performance.

Comment: @frank: It seems that `taffydb` [doesn't support indices](https://github.com/louischatriot/taffydb-benchmark), so it's likely just as fast (and simpler) to simply scan over the records manually (using `indexOf` instead of a regex should generally be faster too).

Answer (score 1):

[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) or [LoDash](http://lodash.com) is really handy for array operations like this.

```
function getMatchingIndex(yourArray, searchTerm) {
  return _.findIndex(yourArray, function(obj) {
    return _.contains(obj, searchTerm);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular, this is achievable by using filters. There's one out of the box that does what you want, and it's even mentioned in the official tutorial:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03

If you want to filter data in a repeater just do:

```
Search: <input ng-model="query">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="dataItem in dataArray | filter:query">
    {{data.name}}
    <p>{{data.family}}</p>
    <p>{{data.email}}</p>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript SQL library. It is faster than SQLite, but still work with SQL on JavaScript arrays.

```
var res = alasql('SELECT * FROM ? WHERE email LIKE ?',[data, enter]);
```

To increase speed of execution you can pre-compile SELECT statement (so, Alasql do not need to
spend time on parsing of SQL statement).

```
// Initialization
var mySelect = alasql.compile('SELECT * FROM ? WHERE email LIKE ?');

// Execution time
var res = mySelect([data, enter]);
```